# neo4j: Invalid input '>': expected whitespace

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to find shortest path in same direction in neo4j by cypher. When I execute query like

```
MATCH p=shortestPath(
    (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})->[*]->(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})
)
RETURN p
```

this error appeared:

```
Invalid input '>': expected whitespace, [ or '-' (line 1, column 43 (offset: 42))
"MATCH (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})->[*1..4]->(hollywood) RETURN DISTINCT hollywood"
```

How can I find shortest path in directed graph in cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using 2 `>` in your query

use

```
(bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]->(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})
```

the relationship direction should be toward the node

```
()-[]->()
```